# Prevent user actions queuing-up while application is busy in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm

I have converted following vb.net codes from this link: [WPF - prevent user actions queuing-up while application is busy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095888/wpf-prevent-user-actions-queuing-up-while-application-is-busy)

ViewModel:

```
Class MainWindow

Private _appIdle As Boolean = True

Private Sub Hooks_OperationStarted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Windows.Threading.DispatcherHookEventArgs)
    ApplicationIdle = False
End Sub

Private Sub Hooks_OperationCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Windows.Threading.DispatcherHookEventArgs)
    ApplicationIdle = True
End Sub

Public Property ApplicationIdle As Boolean
    Get
        Return _appIdle
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        _appIdle = value
        RaisePropertyChanged("ApplicationIdle")
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub MainWindowViewModel()
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Hooks.OperationStarted += AddressOf Hooks_OperationStarted
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Hooks.OperationCompleted += AddressOf Hooks_OperationCompleted
End Sub

End Class
```

MainWindow xaml:

```
IsHitTestVisible="{Binding ApplicationIdle}"
```

But I come across some errors as you can see in this picture: https://prnt.sc/nbn55h

Please tell me how can I solve that errros?

The error says:

> 'RaisePropertyChanged' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to
>   its protection level.

**Note:** I am using .NET 4.5

**Supporting link:** https://jeremybytes.blogspot.com/2016/01/the-evolution-of-inotifypropertychanged.html

Comment: Firstly, error messages are text, so there's no reason to post a picture of them. That goes doubly for a picture hosted on an external site that could disappear any moment.

Comment: Secondly, based on those error messages, you have simply copied and pasted code blindly with no understanding of what the code does. It is incumbent upon you to make the effort to gain that understanding before posting here. The first two error messages at least tell you exactly what to do to fix the issue. What effort have you made to find out what a `RaiseEvent` statement is or does? Apparently none. That a question shows no research is one of the explicitly suggested reasons for casting a down-vote on a question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class MainWindow
   Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged

   Public Event RaisePropertyChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

   Private _appIdle As Boolean = True

   Private Sub Hooks_OperationStarted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Windows.Threading.DispatcherHookEventArgs)
      ApplicationIdle = False
   End Sub

   Private Sub Hooks_OperationCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Windows.Threading.DispatcherHookEventArgs)
      ApplicationIdle = True
   End Sub

   Public Property ApplicationIdle As Boolean
      Get
         Return _appIdle
      End Get
      Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
         _appIdle = value
         RaiseEvent RaisePropertyChanged(Me, New System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("ApplicationIdle"))
      End Set
   End Property

   Public Sub MainWindowViewModel()
      AddHandler Application.Current.Dispatcher.Hooks.OperationStarted, AddressOf Hooks_OperationStarted
      AddHandler Application.Current.Dispatcher.Hooks.OperationCompleted, AddressOf Hooks_OperationCompleted
   End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You included a link, you haven't implemented the code that's there. You have no property changed event, your window doesn't implement inotifypropertychanged and you have noraisepropertychanged method. So when you try and call the method you haven't written that gives an error. Maybe you should switch to c#. VB is now a minority language that few devs and bloggers use. There's a lot more samples in c# you can cut and paste.

Comment: The application idle property should be in the viewmodel.

Comment: @DannyColeiro Maybe you can tell us what you want to do. What functionality your app will perform, etc.

Comment: Put one TextBox to the project like this`<TextBox Text="Hello"/>`

Comment: Put following code the code behind `Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
        AddHandler Application.Current.Dispatcher.Hooks.OperationStarted, AddressOf Hooks_OperationStarted
    End Sub`

Comment: Run this project, try if you can cut Hello text via mouse.

Comment: @DannyColeiro have you tried that yourself? If so, what was the result? Post whatever error(s)/problems that you have encountered.

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b Yes I tried it myself. I am able to cut Hello text. I want I am not able to cut Hello text.